# Embedded form Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have an user class that has a `OneToOne` relationship with `Applicant` and `Company`, I want to propose registering as one of both.
In order to do that, I made 3 forms, an `UserType (email)` , an `ApplicantType (firstName)` and `CompanyType (companyName)` . According to url, I will either generate an ApplicantType or CompanyType to add to the UserType.

To pass the type I use

`$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['data' => ['type' => $type]]);`

so my `UserType` retrieves the type in `$options` and dynamically adds

`->add('applicant', ApplicantType::class) or ->add('company',CompanyType::class)`

I get an error which is

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Entity\User, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of App\Entity\User.
```

What I want to do in the end is, after submit, create and hydrate an Applicant/Company entity that I'll attach to a newly created User entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things solved it :

The data passed to the form should be

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['typeOfUser' => $type]);
```

instead of

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['data' => ['type' => $type]]);
```

Then in the formType add the default value for the key we use to pass the data

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([ 
       'typeOfUser' => 'applicant'
    ]);
}
```